# usage of "真似" in 昔そこそこ強かったウォーロックの連中は似たような真似してたかもな

Tags: meaning, word-usage

Here is a piece of dialogue from the lore of a video game:

> そういや、オラクルじゃないが……昔そこそこ強かったウォーロックの連中は似たような真似してたかもな

The speaker here was just informed about the combat techniques unique to "oracles" (オラクル), in the story ウォーロック need decades of training to achieve the status of オラクル.

But I'm confused by what the speaker means by 真似. The dictionary definitions are as follows:

> 1. imitating; copying; mimicry​
> 2. behavior; behaviour; action; conduct​

I assume definition 2 is the correct usage, however is it behaviour/conduct in terms of how they carry themselves/present themselves, or could it also be referring to a specific action depending on the context? In this case the action being the combat techniques.

Based on this later assumption would I be right in translating the line like so:

> That reminds me, although they're not oracles… maybe warlocks who have been relatively strong for a long time can do something (*combat techniques*) that resembles this.

Answer (score 1):

Definition 2 is correct. 真似 here refers to a specific action (combat technique). Your translation is mostly correct, but could be improved if you drop the "maybe" and treat the 昔 as "in the past" - not "for a long time". So basically, the speaker is reminded of a group of relatively strong warlocks in the past. They were not oracles, but they did something (combat technique) similar. HTH.