# 傷つけるような真似する meaning?

Tags: phrases, conjunctions

I'm stuck on what this could mean. the context is:

おい、庭園や屋敷を傷つけるような真似するんじゃねえぞ？

Is the speaker implying that damage has been done by the other person before? Is this some sort of saying? I'll leave more context below if needed.

Comment: Related: [What 器用な真似 means here?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/90433/43676), [usage of "真似" in 昔そこそこ強かったウォーロックの連中は似たような真似してたかもな](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/61105/43676)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't see how this is anything more than a literal 'Don't do anything that would damage the garden or mansion'. Is 真似 your point of confusion? It not only means 'imitation' but [also](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E7%9C%9F%E4%BC%BC_%28%E3%81%BE%E3%81%AD%29/) 'action, behaviour', especially *stupid* actions.

Also, the sentence doesn't *directly* imply the listener has it done before, but I'd assume either they have, they're the type that might, or that the speaker is very finicky about the mansion's upkeep.

Comment: Ah, that would make sense. And yes 真似 was the point of my confusion, as all my search results came up as "to copy/imitate." I guess I should have made that more clear. Thank you for your response